# What's the monus of the two sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, monoid

Set $A=\{\{1,2\},3\}$, set $B=\{3,4\}$. How do I get $A$ monus $B$. School didn't provide any information about monus and google isn't helping very much.

Comment: What does "monus" mean?  Is this supposed to be "minus"?

Comment: The "monus" is defined on "commutative monoids":https://www.bing.com/search?q=monus&cvid=ceb42cf94d654a6884a34482f82dab24&pglt=43&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=HCTS  but these are sets, not monoids.  If you mean "A minus B"  start with set A and remove anything that is in B.  The only thing in 
A and B is "3" so A minus B= {{1, 2}}.